# How do I open a monkey x .exe file in my python program without it closing immediately after?

Tags: python, monkey

I'm doing a school project and I've got a working logon script in python,  however the rest of my code is in the language monkey X as it is easier to make games within that.

I was wondering if it were possible to open the monkey x file without it closing instantly?

I have tried to open up the .monkey file however this leaves me in the IDE which would look sloppy to an examiner. However the exe file closes instantly. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: So, you want to run another program using Python, presumably in Windows?

Comment: What code are you using to open it up?

Comment: `if LogIn in FileRead:
        LoginScreen.destroy()
   os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Ewan\\Downloads\\LOGON\\new0.3.buildv84f\\glfw3\\gcc_winnt\\Debug\\MonkeyGame.exe')`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get my logon scrip to open up my game script which is in a different language. I can open up the IDE with ease but this looks tacky and so would like to launch the .exe. However the .exe does not remain open after I have opened it.